# Nested loop error handling in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have written a nested loop for file compare in batch script.

```
fc 1.txt 2.txt | findstr "no diff" 

IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (

fc 3.txt 4.txt | findstr "no diff"

IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (
echo 1
goto exit
) ELSE ( 
echo 2
goto exit )))
```

Logic to execute is:
a. If 1&2 and 3&4 are different - echo 1

b. If 1&2 are different but not 3&4 - echo 2

While this code is working fine if there are no differences ie doesn't enter "if" condition. If I try to do requirement for echo 2, it is actually showing echo 1. Not sure how to correct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the parser prepares the lines or blocks of lines (lines in parenthesis), all the variable reads are replaced with the value in the variable **before** starting to execute the code, so your `%errorlevel%` check inside the first `if` will use the same errorlevel value that was used when all the block was parsed.

You can solve it using delayed expansion (`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`) and replacing where needed the read operation in the variable from `%var%` into `!var!`, indicating to the parser that the read operation must be delayed until the execution of the command.

Or you can change the way to check for the errorlevel value, from `if %errorlevel% equ ...` into `if errorlevel n` that will be true if the `errorlevel` value is equal or greater than the indicated `n` value.

In this case it is using a language construct that does not involve variable read operations and is not affected by value replacements at parse time

```
fc 1.txt 2.txt >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    fc 3.txt 4.txt >nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo 1
    ) else (
        echo 2
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it.

```
fc 1.txt 2.txt | findstr "no diff" && goto :done
fc 3.txt 4.txt | findstr "no diff" && (echo 2 & goto :done)
echo 1
:done
```