# WinSCP exit code not reflecting in ERRORLEVEL variable

Tags: batch-file, sftp, winscp

Not sure what is missing in this windows batch and winscp commands, I am struggling to see the ERRORLEVEL value apart from 0 even in negative scenario where winscp command returns errorcode greater than 0.

See the below example.

I have given incorrect username and password and expecting the winscp program to fill ERRORLEVEL greater than 0.

```
ECHO Connecting WinSCP...
SET TMPLOC_WINSCP="C:\Program Files\WinSCP\winscp.com"
set FILE_TO_GET=TEST.txt
%TMPLOC_WINSCP% /command ^
                "option batch abort" ^
                "option confirm off" ^
                "open ""DEVCONN""" ^
                "get %FILE_TO_GET%" ^
                "exit" 
ECHO ERRORLEVEL error code is... %ERRORLEVEL%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO ERROR_WINSCP
echo File downloaded successfully... 

:ERROR_WINSCP
echo Error occured...%ERRORLEVEL%
GOTO END
```

and console log is...

```
Connecting WinSCP...
batch           abort
confirm         off
Searching for host...
Connecting to host...
Authenticating...
Using username "XYZ".
Authenticating with pre-entered password.
Access denied.
Connection has been unexpectedly closed. Server sent command exit status 0.
Authentication log (see session log for details):
Using username "XYZ".
Access denied.

Authentication failed.
ERRORLEVEL error code is... 0
File downloaded successfully...
```

If the above result is expected, then what are the ways to identify when a connection establishment has failed and accordingly script can execute fallback commands..

I am using using winscp 4.3 in windows 8 OS. Please let me know if i am missing anything here....

Comment: Your code looks good and works correctly for me. With exactly the same scenario (Access denied), I get to branch "Error occured". Both with the latest version (5.7.1) and your ancient 4.3. Please upgrade to the latest version, add `/log=path\winscp.log` to command-line and share the log with us.

Comment: I will provide the log from log file shortly. However i see that the windows script returns 0 on happy path flow sometimes and returns 1 sometimes to the same happy path flow. Is there something to do with ERRORLEVEL variable here and also should i consider delayed expansion (setlocal enabledelayedexpansion) as someone provided an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27923028/713414

Comment: @MartinPrikryl It looks for me to be more of an issue with ERRORLEVEL internal variable. I see that WINSCP.com is setting the variable properly...

Comment: It is not related to delayed expansion, as there's no nesting in your batch file.

Answer (score -1):

You can try writing your program properly.

```
ECHO Connecting WinSCP...
"C:\Program Files\WinSCP\winscp.com" /command  "option batch abort" "option confirm off" "open ""DEVCONN""" "get TEST.txt" "exit" 
ECHO ERRORLEVEL error code is... %ERRORLEVEL%
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 If NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Error 0
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 If NOT ERRORLEVEL 2 echo Error 1
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 If NOT ERRORLEVEL 3 echo Error 2
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 If NOT ERRORLEVEL 4 echo Error 3
```

If this shows 0 on error then your program doesn't set exit code.

Comment: I like how you berate him for not writing his program properly and then proceed to write the `if errorlevel` statements backwards. If you put them in the order 3, 2, 1, 0, there's no need for the `if not errorlevel` parts. Alternatively, you can use `%errorlevel%` instead and then _just use it like a normal variable_.

Comment: My way is errorproof, yours isn't. This file was last updated 2007, and it says `Test for errorlevel If errorlevel n if not errorlevel n+1 <command to do> As errorlevel tests always test for a number equal or higher, this code snippet only evaluates if the number is exactly the same. So if testing for errorlevel 6 If errorlevel 6 if not errorlevel 7 Echo The error level was 6 `. Like with %errorlevel% they lead to BUGS.

Comment: You realize you can just say `if %errorlevel% equ 0` and it will only return true if the error level is _exactly_ 0, right?

Comment: Wrong. Very wrong. It will return true if errorlevel is 0 **AND there is no configured environment variable called errorlevel**. Once an errorlevel is created it is no longer will contain the errorlevel again. You can't control the environment, the user might type it, another batch file, or an install program. The user/batch file may do it as a bug rather than purposefuly. So for error proof code do it the way I said if the exact number matters (and again for error proof code you should test for a particular number not is it higher).

Comment: In retrospect, I've only seen `errorlevel` used with `goto`s, which is where the reverse ordering comes into play. I don't use them outside of `choice`, personally. I think in this circumstance, using the `||` operator would be a good idea instead.

Comment: Take findstr. Returns 1 if not found or 2 if something bad happens. Jumping on 1 or higher assumes that only 1 can be returned, not found. So if the file searched is corrupt, you'll act as if it isn't but doesn't contain the string. We all are lazy, and hate typing. I don't always practise what I preach (like yesterday I only tested Not 0 because I was too lazy to look up specific error number - I might fix that now, maybe). But if giving advice, to people that only search the internet, than best practise should be followed mostly.

Comment: @Serenity, Can you advise what is wrong with this line in my example
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO ERROR_WINSCP